# Rails ActiveRecord - Only load certain associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two classes `Address` and `Review`. A review has an address, and an address can have many reviews. I have modeled this by saying `Review belongs_to Address` and that `Address has_many Reviews`.

In the application the main use case is to create a new review. As part of creating a review the user will enter an address, which behind the scenes we try to match against an existing record, or create a new one if necessary.

I have set up routing like this:   `resources :addresses, only: [:new, :create, :show, :update], :as => :reviews, :path => :reviews, :controller => :reviews`.
Which enables me to have URLs like `/reviews/[:id]`.

**What is the best way to load the address and single associated review with id=[:id].**

So far I have

```
@review = Review.find(params[:id])
@address = @review.address
```

But if I then do something like

```
@address.reviews
```

I believe ActiveRecord will load all of the associated Reviews which is not what I want as I am thinking of the Review as the main entity, which has an address as part of it.

**Have I muddled up my design?** Conceptually `an address is part of a review` but I can't see any way of modelling this such that an `address can still have many review`'

**EDIT:**
I think some of my confusion comes from the fact that my views have forms which need to take an Address, because Address has `accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews` which makes all the validation and form building easier.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to address. Yes, `@address.reviews` will return all reviews associated with that address, but why is that a problem for you? You don't have to use that construct if you don't want to.

Comment: It is a problem because in the application use cases I am only ever working with 1 address and 1 review. I don't want to load all of the other reviews

Comment: Why do you think they would be loaded if you don't include `@address.reviews` in your code?

Comment: My apologies Peter, I was confusing things. Please see my comment to universa1's answer for where I was going wrong. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have modelled it correctly imho.

For your form you most likely want something like the following:

```
= form_for @review do |f|
  = f.body
  = f.fields_for :address do |af|
    = af.street
    = af.city
```

and then in your review model you want: accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise the accepts_nested_attributes_for method would work 'backwards' along the association. I can now key my form on review rather than address and everything is much simpler.

Comment: @KnownColor This is not "working backwards". review belongs_to address, so each review points to (contains an id of) an address.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Agreed :)